# What is a good alternative to bpy.data.node_groups.input or .output for 4.0?

Tags: python, add-on

What is a good alternative to `bpy.data.node_groups.input` or `.output`?

Basically, `hostcoll_group = bpt.data.node_groups.new`

Since `.input` and `.output` were removed in 4.0, how would we go about updating this? `.interface`?
[image]

Comment: There's a [migration example in the 4.0 release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API#Node_Groups). See also [docs for `node_tree.interface.new_socket`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeTreeInterface.html#bpy.types.NodeTreeInterface.new_socket).